# TeeChart Event For Color Change

Tags: activex, teechart

I want to know is there any event that will be fired if I modify the Series Color from the editor or How can we know which bar color has been changed by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no event for that. The only way I can think to do this would be to store the array of colors in a temporal variable before opening the editor and compare it with the array of colors when the user closes it.